# Ubuntu Automount corrupts ext4 partitions of Android install?

Tags: filesystem, android, automount, ext4

I've been experimenting with dual-boot between Linux and Android on an x86 device which came with Android + Windows preinstalled (Chuwi Hi10 Pro).

I soon found out that simply booting Ubuntu (either from a live USB stick or from the on-device install) will kill the Android installation (hangs at boot), to the point that only a factory restore will help.

The reason seems to be that Ubuntu automounts every ext4 filesystem it can find, including the Android partitions (system/data/cache/config). I've fixed this by adding the following to `/etc/fstab`:

```
# do _not_ automount the Android partitions
UUID=57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b  /none ext4 ro,noauto 0 0
UUID=57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b1 /none ext4 ro,noauto 0 0
UUID=57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b2 /none ext4 ro,noauto 0 0
UUID=57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b3 /none ext4 ro,noauto 0 0
```

I'm now wondering about two things:

1. What is it that Ubuntu can possibly do to the ext4 partitions that will later cause Android to hang on boot?
2. Could this be related to the fact that apparently all Android partitions share the same UUID?

EDIT: as suggested by mook765, here's the output of `lsblk -f`:

```
NAME         FSTYPE LABEL     UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0                                                            
├─mmcblk0p1  vfat   ANDROIDIA 1389-AFF9                            /boot/efi
├─mmcblk0p2                                                        
├─mmcblk0p3                                                        
├─mmcblk0p4                                                        
├─mmcblk0p5                                                        
├─mmcblk0p6                                                        
├─mmcblk0p7  ext4             57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b 
├─mmcblk0p8  ext4             57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b 
├─mmcblk0p9  ext4             57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b 
├─mmcblk0p10                                                       
├─mmcblk0p11 ext4             57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b 
├─mmcblk0p12 vfat             8A7A-6F97                            
└─mmcblk0p13 ext4             9dadc784-4ed1-4e54-adec-8227b73a0777 /
mmcblk0boot0                                                       
mmcblk0boot1
```

Comment: The UUID's are obviously different. Ubuntu doesn't auto-mount any partitions without telling Ubuntu to do so, the only exception I'm aware of are probably existing swap-partitions.

Comment: 1. If you look closely, you will see that entries 2-4 are not proper UUIDs, but have an extra digit at the end. This is apparently how Ubuntu represents partitions which do have the same UUID; I have confirmed this with `blkid`.

Comment: 2. I have booted an unmodified Ubuntu 18.04 installer from USB, and all four partitions _were_ automounted without further instructions.

Comment: Could you please add the output of `lsblk -f` from the live session to your question?

Comment: See above for lsblk output. Note that these partitions are _not_ mounted now, because that would again kill my Android install.

Comment: I've seen that some file-managers mount all available partitions, for example `pcmanfm-qt`. Which flavor and version of Ubuntu is installed? I'd recommend to create the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-hide-partition-rules` containing lines like `KERNEL=="mmcblk0p7", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"`, one line for each of the Android partitions to let the kernel ignore them entirely.

Comment: Installed distro  is plain Ubuntu 18.04. The udev file is a good idea, but the end result is the same as with fstab - I'm still wondering, however, what the automount does that messes up Android. Maybe the partitions are not cleanly unmounted due to the duplicate UUIDs?